# following the class correctly but the code is not accepted

Tags: list, haskell

I want it to show the desired *n* final numbers, but the GHCi is giving an error in the code

```
nLast :: int -> [a] -> [a]
nLast 0 _ = []
nLast _ [] = []
nLast n (x:xs) = nultimos (n-1) xs
```

Comment: You are here basically taking `n` times the last clause, and then once the first clause. Since none of the clauses return something else than the empty list, the result will be an empty list.

Comment: What is the error? Paying attention to errors, learning to understand them, will help you in the future fix your own code. So get in the habit of posting specific errors now, and we can help you better until then.

Comment: `nultimos` ==/== `nLast`.

Answer (score 1):

You can work with two enumerators over the list. You give one of the enumeraters a head start of `n` items and each time you let both the enumerators make one hope. If the first runner reaches the empty list, then we know that the second runner has `n` items they still need to enumerate over.

We thus can implement this with:

```
nLast :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
nLast n ls = go (drop n ls) ls
    where go (_:xs) (_:ys) = …
          go [] ys = …
```

here you still need to fill in the `…` parts. I leave this as an exercise.

In the above example there is a pattern that we do not cover, a pattern where the first list is a non-empty list `(_:_)` and the second is empty `[]`. We know that this can never happen, it might still be better however to add a clause for this.

Comment: The lazy pattern match on `[]` is pretty subtle. Especially for someone who can't figure out how to solve this problem on their own, I would suggest either explaining it or leaving it out.

Comment: @amalloy: agreed. Updated.